# External libraries in Visual Studio 2010 projects

Tags: visual-studio-2010, dll, projects-and-solutions

I have a question devoted to proper libraries management in Visual Studio 2010.
The thing is that I have solution with few projects in it ("A", "B", "C", "D"). One of the project is a "library" project ("A"), where I have already put some classes, which are useful for me in the other projects within the same solution.
Now, I have realized that I need to use another, third-party library ("E") from the Internet, which is distributed in .dll files.
My question is: How to setup project in VS 2010 which needs this external library such that these dlls stay within my "library" project "A", but can be used in the other project "B"?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to share third party dependencies across multiple projects, simply put the third-party DLL `E.dll` in a common folder and reference this assembly from `A` and `B` via project-->add reference (both pointing to the same /folder/e.dll).

Comment: Where does the folder be created? Should it be at solution level i.e., outside all projects? I created a folder at solution level but it is not accessible from Add Reference dialog box. Please reply.